# Парсинг Тега Script с выводом конкретных данных из него

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть сайт с которого нужно достать из тега SCRIPT, items на фото ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что я написал,

```
from re import T
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import urllib
import json



data = {
    'AUTH_FORM': 'Y',
    'TYPE': 'AUTH',
    'backurl': '/',
    'USER_LOGIN': '****',
    'USER_PASSWORD': '****',
    'USER_REMEMBER': 'Y',
    'Login': 'Войти'
}
url = 'https://pro.ekt.kz/catalog/kabel_provod/?perpage=100&PAGEN_1=1'
r = requests.post(url, data=data).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all("script")
items = products[47]

data = json.loads(items)
print(data['items'])
```

Сам сайт https://pro.ekt.kz/

Вот что выдает мне в терминале.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу достать из тега script (массив?) items?

Comment: так глянте items, довидите напильником до JSON-а подобного формата

Comment: @СергейШ, получается обернуть сам дата[item]?